# I've lost my Internet connection

Tags: networking

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10.  I had a perfectly good wireless Internet connection, but I tried to speed it up by going to a wired connection and now I have no connection at all.  When I go to the Connections section of System Settings, I can create connections (I think) but I can't figure out how to activate them. I can't even connect to my LAN.  I thought that **ifconfig** might help, but lacking the connection I can't install it. How can I get going again?

Comment: Instead of `ifconfig`, use `ip`. What's the output of `ip addr show`?

Comment: 20.10 is beyond support and end of life.  as such it is off topic here.  You will need to upgrade to a newer OS version; you should stick to wireless or ethernet, not both.

Comment: To upgrade your OS without an internet connection, see this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=linuxonibm/liabu/liabunointernetupdateubuntu.htm

Comment: I mistyped the version number - it is 21.10, not 20.10.  I hope someone can now answer the question.